# SQL query to find last day code was used

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a query to find out the last day a code was used by each Company.

```
SELECT T1.comp, T1,code, T1 date
FROM T1
```

I want to add `MAX` to `T1.date` but unsure of the sytax ... or something similar

Perhaps I can create a DATE field by concatenating T1.period & T1,yr but struggle with syntax ..

```
DateValue(Str(T1.period) & Str(T1.yr))
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Order the table on the date descending, and keep only the first row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 T1.comp, T1.code, T1.date
FROM T1
ORDER BY T1.date DESC
```

Comment: Trouble is I need for every Company of which there are 300+ - thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregate function.  you can find more details here:
http://www.sqlcourse2.com/agg_functions.html

for the mean time try:

```
SELECT T1.comp, max(T1 date)
FROM T1
GROUP BY t1.comp
```

Comment: Thanks Tom will give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

By the comments on [@ThomasG answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324723/5353753) I assume you want the max for each `comp` that has more then 300 records?

If so, use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` :

```
SELECT T1.comp, max(T1 date)
FROM T1
GROUP BY t1.comp
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 300
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT T1.comp, T1.code, MAX(T1.date) AS LastDate
FROM T1
GROUP BY T1.comp, T1.code
```

Comment: No joy!
Perhaps I can create a DATE field by concatenating T1.period & T1,yr but struggle with syntax ..

`code`DateValue(Str(T1.period) & Str(T1.yr))`code`

Comment: share that detail in the question, add information about both the column and some possible values to understand it better.

Comment: Thanks Jatin will do now - ta